# Save OneToOne relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'role_id',
    ];
    .........
    public function language() {
        return $this->hasOne(Language::class, 'language_id');
    }
}
```

And Language model :

```
class Language extends Model
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'iso'
];

/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now When I try to save user :

```
$newUser->language()->save(Language::find($input['language']));
```

I get the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'language_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `languages` set `language_id` = 4, `languages`.`updated_at` = 2021-08-02 13:51:32 where `id` = 1)"
```

User migration :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->default(UserRoles::TRANSLATOR);
        $table->integer('language_id')->references('id')->on('languages')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Language migration :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('iso')->unique();
    });
}
```

I confirm that I have language id inside `users` table and I don't have user_id inside `language` table, because I want to keep just language_id inside table. What can I try next?

Comment: could you post the migrations files for both models?

Comment: your relationships.. I think it should be `User` belongsTo `Language` and `Language` `hasMany`/`hasOne` Users..

Comment: @Prospero I added.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `hasOne` in User model:

```
public function language() {
    return $this->hasOne(Language::class, 'language_id');
}
```

eloquent assumes that `languages` table would have `language_id`. Hence the error 'no language_id in languages table'

So, `hasOne` should be defined in the the Language model.

```
//Language model
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::class); //this assumes users table would have language_id
}
```

And, the `belongsTo` should be defined in User model.

```
//User model
public function language() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Language::class);
}
```

Comment: just to confirm: in your Lang model, now, you have user function defining a hasOne relationship and in your user model you have langague function defining a belongsTo relationship? Also remove that language_id.

Answer (score 0):

as the first answer, change the sintax of your relationship and add the language_id to the fillable array

user model

```
protected $fillable = [
  'email',
  'password',
  'role_id',
  'language_id'
];
public function language() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Language::class);
}
```

and on user creation

```
$user = User::create(
  'email' => ...
  'password' => ...
  'role_id' => ...
  'language_id' => $input['language']
);
```

you can see more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method, so in this case if you want to use the save method on this relation you must do it like

```
$language = Language::find($input['language']);

$language->user()->save($newuser);
```

I suggest use the Laravel documentation sintax for the relationship in migration

```
$table->foreignId('language_id')->constrained()->nullable();
```

Comment: what's the issue after this changes?

Comment: the same issue @Prospero

Comment: did you add language_id to fillable??? did you already runned migrate command?